# How to display a Video stream from Camera on Raspberry pi with Win iot with some image processing

Tags: c++, xaml, opencv, windows-iot-core-10

1. I am trying to build a webcam based face detector using Raspberry pi as the base and Win 10 IOT as the OS
2. the image i'm trying to capture will come from a webcam having its own API
3. OpenCV is required for me to detect the object as any Haar classifier can be used
4. I am not able to port my Console appln onto the ARM base
5. Xaml required for the Universal Windows APP does not support the video capture as an output type im using the Image constructor
   NEW POINT
6. When using Videocapture with our code , when writing the image to mat type , weather we used cap>>MAt or cap.retrive(mat,0) wew got the same exception error 
   this->_M_dispatcher._Ptr  was a nullptr .

help with any of these points is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> > I am trying to build a webcam based face detector using Raspberry pi as the base and Win 10 IOT as the OS.

Windows IoT has full support for some USB web camera, make sure your device is supported in the compatible [list](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist#Cameras).

> > The image i'm trying to capture will come from a webcam having its own API

Does the *own API* support Windows ARM platform? If not, you may need to compile it targeting ARM, if it's not open-sourced, request from the webcam manufacture.

> > OpenCV is required for me to detect the object as any Haar classifier can be used.

Windows IoT has full support for OpenCV thanks for Microsoft's [porting](https://github.com/Microsoft/opencv). You can follow the tutorial [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/opencv) to compile it for Windows ARM.

If you're developing UWP app using C#, you may need to create a wrapper class around the OpenCV dlls. Alternatively, the latest release of [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) introduces support for UWP.

> > I am not able to port my Console appln onto the ARM base
> >     Xaml required for the Universal Windows APP does not support the video capture as an output type

Could you please provide some code sample?

Comment: thanks for replying , im developing the app on c++ with xaml , the camera im using is OCCAm omni 60 , and i am not really sure what to do with it , this header was attached to it [this is the sdk link](http://occamvisiongroup.com/knowledgebase/software-development-kits/), the sdk just includes 1 header file and im not sure how to compile it for arm

Comment: and as far as the Video capture command goes , the dll file does not exist for arm on compilation ...so stuck there, win rt is supported but windows with xaml in their new universal app format is not available .

Comment: So you don't have the source code for the sdk and the exisiting dll is not targeting windows ARM? In this case, you cannot use it on RP3 with windows iot core. You have the reference the arm version of the dll assembly.

Comment: is there a way to access the camera onto an opencv data type ? in xaml and windows UWP ..if there is id be glad if you could share it . capturing the image into a data type is the issue i'm facing